# A Virtual?...Desktop? question....(wondering if this is possible)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, windows-7

If I already have Ubuntu (14.04LTS) and Windows (7 installed first, recently upgraded to 10) on separate partitions, is there a way to run both OS's with any form of virtual machines, or, would one create another partition with something like a 'virtual desktop server' possibly with Debian? and run that environment with any OS's involved? Would separate disk drive(s) be of use? Which OS runs the hardware (WIN Licence issues)? I'm sure some people have come across a similar situation. Thanks.

Edit:
To Run an OS or multiple OS's on a current host operating system (pref: Ubuntu) Using existing partitions on the same disk drive, or possibly use separate drives and set up something like a 'desktop server' OS - I was thinking using Debian for that. Would a version of Apache assist? Is there a way of using view ports to achieve the result of using an existing guest OS(s) from within a host machine with the 'guest' already installed on a separate partition, that is not reinstalling the 'guest' but running it from the partition where it is currently installed.

Apologies, Is this better explained? It comes from the situation of having to re-boot a dual booted machine, get's a little tedious. Thanks.

Edit: I contacted a systems consultant who recommended Xenserver to run multiple OS's of a single computer. I'm going to have a look at that software, see how it goes.

Comment: Edit: To Run an OS or multiple OS's on a current operating system (pref: Ubuntu) Using existing partitions on the same drive, or possibly separate drives with a 'desktop server' OS - I was thinking Debian. Apologies.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to run an operating system using VirtualBox or something, but storing the OS on it's own partition/drive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there are things you should be aware of. At least in the past, switching hardware for Windows has caused issues. That means you'd either always run Windows virtualized or always on metal. However, this is very rarely an issue with Ubuntu. I don't know what the situation is with Windows 10.

So what you can do, is to have Windows on one drive and Ubuntu on another. Then you can create a VirtualBox VM definition that uses the Ubuntu drive directly as a raw device. That way you can choose whether to boot it on metal or as a virtual machine while running Windows. However, you *must not* boot the VM while Ubuntu is running, or you'll break your system.

I've always done this with separate physical disks and it works quite well. I'm not sure if it's possible to do the same using different partitions on the same disk, but I wouldn't recommend it, or at least you should investigate it thoroughly before you make an attempt. Having two OSs accessing the disk directly at the same time is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking so this may not be responsive, but it is certainly possible to run Windows in a virtual machine on an Ubuntu computer, or Ubuntu in a virtual machine on a Windows computer, or Ubuntu in a virtual machine on an Ubuntu computer, etc, etc.

You do not need to repartition to run virtual machines.  Nor are separate disk drives required (but they are not ruled out).

The "host" i.e. physical machine runs on the hardware.  Licensing is still required in the "guest", i.e. virtual machine to the same extent that it would be in a physical machine.  In other words, to have a fully operational Windows installation you need to jump through the same Windows verification hoops that you do on a physical machine.